# Decoding an encoded text

Tags: java

I have below logic to encode a text, but when I try to decode it I am not getting expected result:

```
private static String encodeText(String input) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            int d = (int) c;
            d = d*2 + i;
            builder.append((char)d);
        }
        return builder.reverse().toString();
    }
```

Here is my decode logic, I just tried to reverse the logic of encoding to decode the text:

```
private static String decode(String input) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            int data = (int)c;
            data = data - i;
            data = (data)/2;
            b.append((char)data);
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
```

If I encode the text `hello` then the encoded value is `âÛÚËÐ`, when I try to decode it then I am getting it as `fdlmq`

Where is the issue in this logic, can you please help me?

Comment: Is 'd' too big to fit into a 'char' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since after encoding the characters, you reverse the string

```
return builder.reverse().toString();
```

you need to change integer you subtract as

```
data = data - (size - i - 1);
```

where `size` is the length of the String (`input.length()`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reverse the string again at the start of `decode` since you reversed it in `encodeText()` and then again at the end since you build the string beginning at the end.

```
private static String decode(String input) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    input = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        int data = (int)c;
        data = data - i;
        data = (data)/2;
        b.append((char)data);
    }
    return b.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: don't the second reverse here is redundant?

Comment: @oreh no since he decodes the string starting with the end. So decoding `âÛÚËÐ` would result in `olleh`. Every character is correctly decoded they are just appended in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

So youve "hi"
You do h*2+0 = x, and i*2+1 = y
Now you reverse it and have "yx".

Now you decode "yx"
You do x-1,...

The thing is, you encoded x with +0, not -1. shouldn't use i here, but input.length() - 1 - i.

Answer (score 0):

It is because i is different in two methods.
Change your decode logic to following.

```
 private static String decode(String input)
  {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      char c = input.charAt(i);
      int data = (int) c;
      data = data - (input.length()-1-i);
      data = (data) / 2;
      b.append((char) data);
    }
    return b.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is amistake in your decode method data = data - (input.length()-i);

try like this

```
 private static String decode(String input) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int length = input.length() - 1;
    for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
      char c = input.charAt(i);
      int data = (int)c;
      data = data - (length-i);
      data = (data)/2;
      b.append((char)data);
    }
    return b.toString();
  }
```